# What is the URL for alfresco CMIS 1.1 queries

Tags: json, alfresco, cmis

I'm trying to figure out how to use the new browser binding in Alfresco 4.2.  I get that the service URL is
https://server.com/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser

And I'm able to do requests for objects and paths in a restful manner
https://server.com/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser/root/Sites
https://server.com/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser?objectId=xxx

But what I don't understand is how to translate the specification's "selectors" and "actions" into URLs.  For instance, I have no idea what the URL for doing a "query" is.

http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/cs01/CMIS-v1.1-cs01.html#x1-5540003

I've tried all of these to no avail:
https://server.com/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser/doQuery?q=select ...
https://server.com/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser/root/doQuery?q=select ...
https://server.com/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser?cmisaction=query&statement=select....
https://server.com/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser/cmisselector=query&q=select...

I think I'm having trouble reading the specification.  The specification lists out a bunch of "selector" and "actions" for named URLS (service url, repository url, object url, etc).  But doesn't explain how those are to be formed into URL strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute a query with HTTP GET and HTTP POST.

A HTTP GET URL end with: .../browser?cmisselector=query&q=select...

For A HTTP POST example see:
http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/os/examples/browser/doQuery-request.log